# serviceWorker notificationclick never fires using Blazor WASM .NET Core Hosted

Tags: javascript, blazor, service-worker, blazor-webassembly

**Edit: Just tested on firefox and it's working, but not in chrome on desktop.**

Everything else thus far has worked fine, but it seems like `notificationclick` just doesn't want to fire at all.

I have this in service-worker.js:

```
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
    console.log("Notification clicked");
    event.notification.close();
    // Define actions to take when the notification is clicked
    event.waitUntil(
        console.log("Notification clicked"),
        clients.matchAll({ type: 'window' }).then(windowClients => {
            // This is where you'd put your logic for handling the notification click
            // For example, focusing an existing window or opening a new one
            console.log("Handling notification click inside waitUntil");

            // Example: Open a new window if no client windows are open
            if (!windowClients.length) {
                return clients.openWindow('https://example.com');
            }
        })
    );
});

self.addEventListener('push', event => {
    const data = event.data.json();
    console.log(data, "Notification data");
    event.waitUntil(
        self.registration.showNotification(data.title, {
            body: data.body,
            icon: data.icon,
            data: { callbackUrl: data.callbackUrl }
            //actions: [{ action: 'view', title: 'View' }]
        })
    );
});
```

This is how I setup my push notifications and subscriptions and everything except the `notificationclick` handler is working.

This is in `jsfunctions.js` and gets called when SignalR connects:

```
async function subscribeToPush(signalRService) {
    console.log("Checking for existing subscription...");
    const serviceWorker = await navigator.serviceWorker.ready;
    const existingSubscription = await serviceWorker.pushManager.getSubscription();

    if (existingSubscription) {
        console.log("Existing subscription found. Verifying with server...");
        // Send the existing subscription to the server for verification
        const isVerified = await sendSubscriptionToServer(signalRService, existingSubscription);
        console.log("Subscription verified with the server.");
    } else {
        console.log("No existing subscription found. Creating new subscription.");
        await createAndSendSubscription(signalRService);
    }
}

async function createAndSendSubscription(signalRService) {
    const serviceWorker = await navigator.serviceWorker.ready;
    const subscription = await serviceWorker.pushManager.subscribe({
        userVisibleOnly: true,
        applicationServerKey: urlBase64ToUint8Array('key')
    });

    console.log("Subscription", subscription);
    console.log("Sending subscription to backend...");

    var finalSub = {
        endpoint: subscription.endpoint,
        p256dh: arrayBufferToBase64(subscription.getKey("p256dh")),
        auth: arrayBufferToBase64(subscription.getKey("auth"))
    };

    try {
        await signalRService.invokeMethodAsync("SendSubscriptionToBackend", finalSub);
        console.log("Subscription sent to backend successfully.");
    } catch (exception) {
        console.log("Error sending subscription to backend", exception);
    }
}
async function sendSubscriptionToServer(signalRService, subscription) {
    var finalSub = {
        endpoint: subscription.endpoint,
        p256dh: arrayBufferToBase64(subscription.getKey("p256dh")),
        auth: arrayBufferToBase64(subscription.getKey("auth"))
    };

    try {
        await signalRService.invokeMethodAsync("SendSubscriptionToBackend", finalSub);
        console.log("Subscription sent to backend successfully.");
        return true;
    } catch (exception) {
        console.log("Error sending subscription to backend", exception);
        return false;
    }
}
```

The problem is that `notificationclick` never logs anything to console or seems to do anything at all when I click the notification.

It's worth noting that I'm testing this in visual studio locally at the moment using the IIS default debugger.

Answer (score 1):

So, weirdly this didn't work while testing locally, but works just fine after deployed.

I spent an hour trying to get it working locally, tested in firefox and saw it working, so I decided to just deploy and give it a go.

Now it all works... very strange and confusing, but I'm guessing some sort of visual studio browser link interfering? Not sure.

Comment: I have seen this same issue. It didn't work for me when testing in the browser instance that VS starts. I am able to get it to work in my dev environment by using a real domain pointed at my VS project port via Haproxy, and a normal Chrome instance. Part of the problem is that it won't work for localhost. The other problem is the VS started instance of Chrome.

Comment: Awesome, thanks I believe that's part of the problem. I think the browser linking may be breaking things there